# setInterval not clearing properly in React.js when dealing with react-youtube package

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I'm a fledgling developer and I'm trying to design an SPA in React that uses YouTube API to retrieve data. Using that data it tracks whether or not users have watched a video. I do this by calculating the percentage watched using some simple math that updates every five seconds with setInterval. I'm doing all this in combination with a npm package called "react-youtube."

Inside the component I have a function called generatePercent() that grabs the event data as per the react-youtube documentation, and generates the percentage, this is triggered when the user hits play on the video. Unfortunately, I can't get this interval to clear when a user hits pause. Worse yet, the app seems to be generating multiple instances of setInterval as well.

I've tried everything from placing this in the ComponentDidMount/ComponentWillUnmount to using tracking the state of the player inside the state of the app and using if/else statements to say the movie is paused then clear the interval. I've looked at plenty of examples on reactjs.org and other similar issues on this site and nothing is working. I'm probably just not noticing something easy, but I'm genuinely at a loss. A lot of the problems seem to be stemming from the fact that I have to tap into event.target.property-of-the-thing-i-want as per the youtube-react documentation, and that's causing a few headaches for me to retrieve it otherwise. Any help would very, very appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import YouTube from 'react-youtube'

class Player extends Component {
render() {
    // setIsPlaying is code that sets the state this.state.isPlaying   in App.js 
    // this.state.isPlaying is passed down from state as props into this component
    const { currentMovie, setIsPlaying, isPlaying } = this.props

    const opts = {
        height: '500px',
        width: '100%',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            controls: 0
        }
    }

    const setState = (event) => {
        const playerState = event.target.getPlayerState()
        setIsPlaying(playerState)
    }

    const generatePercent = (event) => {
        const getPercentage = setInterval(() => {
            const position = event.target.getCurrentTime()
            const duration = event.target.getDuration()
            const percent = Math.round((position / duration) * 100) + '%'
            console.log(percent)
        }, 5000)

        if (isPlaying === 1) {
            return getPercentage
        } else {
            clearInterval(getPercentage)
        }
    }

    return (
        <YouTube
            videoId={currentMovie}
            opts={opts}
            onReady={setState}
            onStateChange={setState}
            onPlay={generatePercent}
            onPause={generatePercent}
        />
    )
}
};

export default Player;
```

I just want the setInterval to generate the percent when users hit play, and pause the generation when users hit pause. Right now the setInterval does not pause and it creates multiple instances of setInterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your interval somewhere outside of the generatePercent function. Once that function is done running, all variables declared in that function will be unreachable. When you run the function a second time, that getPercentage variable will be null.
You can store your interval in the component state like so:

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
      myInterval: null,
   };
}
```

Your generatePercent function could then look like this:

```
generatePercent() {
  // Fetch the interval from the state
  let { myInterval, isPlaying } = this.state;

  if (!isPlaying) {
    // If the video has stopped, clear the interval
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    // Delete the reference or the (!myInterval) check below will still return false
    myInterval = null;
  } else if(!myInterval) {
    // Create an interval
    myInterval = setInterval(() => this.handleInterval(), 1000);
  }

  // Save the interval into the component state
  this.setState({myInterval});
}
```

With a working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Robb216/mp835Luy/22/).

Comment: This is very helpful. I didn't think to set the interval as part of the state. I'll try that in just a few. Thanks so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one interval, you'll probably want to set it as an instance property on your component, rather than putting it into a function in your render method. Your render method will run anytime your component gets new props or updates its state.

e.g

```
class Player extends Component {
  interval = null;
  render() {
  // reuse and clear the same interval as this.interval here
  }
}
```

I'd suggest making it an instance property, rather than setting it to your state, since these kinds of things tend to cause more renders than necessary.

I'd probably suggest throwing your functions as class methods as well. Basically avoid defining things inside of render than need to be available across renders.

e.g. see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) how the `handleFormSubmit` and `handleInputChange` methods are defined?

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try. I'm still learning the ins-and-outs so I forget about these things. Appreciate your time.